# Expo json Unexpected End of Input

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, post, async-await

I have a pretty simple bit of javascript that sends a post command. As expected, I get a promise from the fetch command, but when trying to use the promise with `response.json()` I get an Unexpected end of input Syntax Error at the line indicated below. I get no issue when using `response.text()` and various other methods, it just seems to be `.json()` that breaks stuff. I am using React Native and this same code has worked fine with Node.js.

```
async function postData (url, data) {
  const params = {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  let response = await fetch(url,params);
  var responseJson = await response.json();//This seems to be the problem
  return response;
}
```

Here is some more code that may be helpful.

```
function postStuff() {
  var url = "http://192.4.20.69:1337";
  postData(url, data)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("App Executed");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Text>Hello!!</Text>
      <Button
        title="Post"
        color={"#696969"}
        accessibilityLabel="Click to send message"
        onPress={postStuff}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any help figuring out why `.json()` is breaking this would be appreciated. I'd like to try sticking with using fetch but if I need to I can use one of the other ways of handling json but I think I may still run into the issue concerning `.json()`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue lies in the server side response.
response.json() fail if no json is returned.
I suggest to you to check server response by adding a try catch around response.json() and print out response.text() in the catch .
It could also be due to the fact that your response is missing the required header content-type and fetch doesn't know how to parse it.
So you could try yo do something like this

```
async function postData (url, data) {
  const params = {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  let response = await fetch(url,params);
  try{
     return await response.json();//This seems to be the problem
   }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    const textResponse = await response.text();
    return JSON.parse(textResponse)
  }
  return response;
}
```

Also I notice that you are returning response instead of responseJson that also could be the problem here

Comment: I checked to see if it's an issue of not being valid JSON but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I have used the same `.json()` function quite similarly in a different project with no issues and I have used some test APIs to see if maybe it was mine in specific. Thanks for the ideas though